# In app purchase worked in Swift 2 but doesn't now that I've updated to Swift 3 and Xcode 8

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, in-app-purchase, swift3

As the title says, I had code for an in app purchase to remove ads working in Swift 2 and then updated to Swift 3 and updated the code as well. It gets to the point where it sends the payment request to Apple but then won't run `func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])` called in `func buyProduct()`. Here's the code:

```
//  MainScene.swift
//  Contain
//
//  Created by Phil Javinsky III on 9/16/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Phil Javinsky III. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit
import StoreKit

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
var noAds: Bool = false
var fetched: Bool = false
var product = SKProduct()
var productID = "containRemoveAds"
var readyForIAP: Bool = false

class MainScene: SKScene, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    var touchLocation: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
    var start, leaderboards, rate, removeAds: SKSpriteNode!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    if defaults.bool(forKey: "purchased") {
        print("Already purchased")
        bannerAd.isHidden = true
        noAds = true
    }
    else {
        print("Not purchased")
        if !fetched {
            print("Fetching")
            getProductInfo()
            fetched = true
        }
    }

    start = self.childNode(withName: "start") as! SKSpriteNode
    leaderboards = self.childNode(withName: "leaderboards") as! SKSpriteNode
    leaderboards.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -1150)
    rate = self.childNode(withName: "rate") as! SKSpriteNode
    rate.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -1350)
    removeAds = self.childNode(withName: "removeAds") as! SKSpriteNode
    removeAds.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -1550)

    SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    touchLocation = touches.first!.location(in: self)

    if start.contains(touchLocation) {
        let game: GameScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")!
        game.scaleMode = .aspectFit //.resizeFill?
        view?.presentScene(game, transition: SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1))
    }
    else if leaderboards.contains(touchLocation) {
        //showLeaderboard()
    }
    else if rate.contains(touchLocation) {
        /*let url = NSURL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/whack-a-diglett/id1141187647?ls=1&mt=8")

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url! as URL) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url! as URL)
        }*/
    }
    else if removeAds.contains(touchLocation) {
        let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Remove Ads", message: "Remove ads or restore a previous purchase.", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Remove Ads", style: .default, handler:
            { action -> Void in
                print("Remove Ads")
                if readyForIAP {
                    self.buyProduct()
                }
                else {
                    print("Not ready for IAP")
                    let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Error", message: "Something went wrong, try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                    self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Restore Purchase", style: .default, handler:
            { action -> Void in
                print("Restore purchase")
                if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
                }
            }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}

func getProductInfo() {
    //print("About to fetch the products")

    // Check if allowed to make the purchase
    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
        let productIdentifier: NSSet = NSSet(object: productID)
        let productsRequest: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifier as! Set<String>)
        productsRequest.delegate = self
        productsRequest.start()
        //print("Fetching Products")
    }
    else {
        print("can't make purchases")
    }
}

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    var products = response.products
    if (products.count != 0) {
        product = products[0]
        print(product.localizedTitle)
        print(product.localizedDescription)
        print(product.price)
        readyForIAP = true
        print("Ready for IAP")
    }
    else {
        print("Product not found")
    }
}

func buyProduct() {
    print("Sending payment request to Apple")
    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment as SKPayment)
}

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    print("Received payment transaction response from Apple")
    for transaction in transactions {
        switch transaction.transactionState {
        case .purchased:
            print("Product Purchased")
            defaults.set(true, forKey: "purchased")
            bannerAd.isHidden = true
            noAds = true
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
        case .failed:
            print("Purchased Failed")
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
        case .restored:
            print("Restored")
            let alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Restored", message: "Purchase restored, ads removed.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            defaults.set(true, forKey: "purchased")
            bannerAd.isHidden = true
            noAds = true
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
        default:
            print("DEFAULT")
            break
        }
    }
}

func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Error Fetching product information");
}

}
```

Comment: Why do you remove `self` as an `SKPaymentQueue` observer long before you are done observing?

Comment: To put it more strongly, why would you _ever_ remove the observer?

Comment: I was removing the transaction observer at the end of didMoveToView because if the program left MainScene.swift, went to GameScene.swift, and then returned to MainScene it would add another transaction observer resulting in an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error and crash. I've moved the remove action to be in sync with the start button and it's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you removing the transaction observer in didMoveToView? That makes no sense.

Add the transaction observer in didMoveToView

```
 SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
```

and only remove it when your app closes.

Maybe its also a good idea to move your IAP code into another helper class or something, your code is hard to read like this.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your input. Now that I think about it I'm not sure how this worked in swift 2 but it did. I moved the remove action to be in sync with the start button so if the user leaves MainScene.swift it removes the transaction observer so there are not multiple observers if the user returns to MainScene.swift.